# Make change for existing webpage using Javascript for others

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently i received a company's interview request but first they asked me to complete a assessment: They gave me a link with a calendar app they made, and wants me to make some changes by using javascript and host it so they can see.

What I was trying to do was right click on that page and "view page source" and copy paste all the html and css file, but since there are pictures and different link path name, I cannot recover the original webpage exactly.

My question is how can I write javascript directly online or do you have any other suggestion in simple way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: File -> Save page as ... (might be named/located differently in different browsers) usually gives you the option to save not only the HTML, but also all linked external resources ...

Comment: You may want to try something like codepen or jsfiddle, but anyway if you need particular help on it, you should paste some of your code. This is not a specific javascript question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) In order to avoid hosting the files by yourself, you could use services like https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/:

- copy all the markup from the original app
- update image&resources references to include the original hostname
- copy the script you are requested to modify and update the reference in the markup so that it is used instead of the original one
- modify the script
- send the example as codepen/jsfiddle
- ???
- profit ;-)

B) Another option would be to:

- save your page to a file (Ctrl+S, "Webpage, Complete")
- host it on https://github.com/
- make your change
- commit & push
- use something like https://htmlpreview.github.io/ for preview

Comment: It works thanks! I copied all the files into codepen and show the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Since they want you to host it, you'll need the original information.  But the links for images & such should be available from your page, as well.

If you want the whole thing to work with, though, I recommend getting to know [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com%20fiddler).  It's a software proxy that allows you to capture incoming and outgoing HTTP traffic.

(I'm assuming the site in question is not secured)

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use this way when finish code.

Answer (score 0):

You could hit `Ctrl+S` in your browser, and save the page as "Webpage, complete". The browser will download the main HTML and all linked files (in a single folder), so you can open the main HTML and work on it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help. I solved this problem(Now i found it was a silly question I asked..) by simply copy all the file from original webpage. Now i am using CodePen to code this.